# Conditionally filtering for cases across multiple variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering

I am trying to filter for cases in my dataframe which are > 3 across many variables (i.e., show all cases in the dataframe which have a value greater than 3). I have several hundred variables so cannot do this manually. I've tried to write a for loop to execute this but have failed so far. Once found, I need to replace values > 3 with "NA" so that they will not be included in analyses.

Here is an example of the code which works for each variable in particular using tidy verse(dplyr):

```
library(tidyverse) 
dataframe %>% select(var1) %>% filter(var1 > 3) %>% glimpse()
```

This code outputs the refined dataframe where values > 3. Apologies if this is a simple question as I am new to R.

UPDATE: 
The below code outputs all cases where one variable/column contains a value greater than 3.

```
filter_all(dataframe, any_vars(. > 3)) %>% glimpse()
```

Instead, I need it to show only the variable/column containing a value greater than 3, rather than showing all variables where at least one variable/column is greater than 3. This is because I need replace these values with "NA"

Comment: What is your desired output? You mention that you need to *'replace these values >3 with "NA"'* is that the main goal? Do you want a single data frame with all rows where any variable is > 3 are filtered out? Or do you want individual data frames for each variable?

Comment: Generally, you should see the `?if_all` help page. You can do, e.g., `mtcars %>% filter(if_all(everything(), \(x) x > 0))` to keep rows from `mtcars` where all values are > 0. Instead of `everything()` you can specify certain columns, and you could use `\(x) x <= 3` to keep rows where all values are <= 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please read and incorporate elements from [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1082435). Especially the aspects of using `dput()` for the input and then an explicit example of your expected dataset?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.